# Any idea how to grab just names from the following values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a table with just one fieldname called Names.

There are several rows of long values associated with this fieldname.

Below is an example of how long each row of values could be.

```
Names

0000000024DOE JAMES JAN E102/02/1988107/11/2007 13011UNASSIGNED EMPLOYEEID 0175420670 3303302 - DY1 B100 1000 - 07/11/2007 0000028800 0000040849 0000173045 0000021600 
etc
etc
```

Is it possible to just extract only the names from the lists similar to above?

For instance, we would like to extract DOE JAN while ignoring the rest of the values.

Sometimes, the names have a middle initial.

Example:

```
0000000024DOE JAMES JAN E102/02/1988107/11/2007 13011UNASSIGNED EMPLOYEEID 0175420670 3303302 - DY1 B100 1000 - 07/11/2007 0000028800 0000040849 0000173045 0000021600
```

In this example, the value we would like to extract is Doe Jan E.

Any ideas how to go about it if it is possible?

Comment: So, you don't want the "James" part?   Are the field lengths all consistent (i.e. will you always have a 10 digit number preceding the name)?

Comment: REGEX should be the way to achieve this

Comment: Some more data samples might make it easier for people to give you the right regex patterns.

Comment: If you can provide more information about the other fields either side of the one you're after, it'll help get a more efficient/effective answer.  Eg the numbers prior to the name - is that field always 10 digits?  Does the following field always start with `E102` or `Ennn` or what format is it etc?

Comment: Thanks all for the overwhelming quick response. Yes, @Mike, we will always have 10 digits preced name and also, 3 digits after name.

For instance, you will see E109, the E is the middle initial. If there is no middle initial, you will see 3 digits after names. I have added more sample code above.

Comment: you should try substring() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the name starts at position 11 and it terminated with 3 numbers and a slash, the following should do it for you.

```
SUBSTRING(Names, 11, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]/%', Names) - 11)
```

PATINDEX returns the location based on a wildcard pattern.